# A sentence with double negative

Tags: tenses, ambiguity, semantics, double-negation

I came across the following sentence in Kurt Vonnegut's book Slaughterhouse Five.

> “Trout would have gone upstairs if Billy hadn't asked him not to.”

If this sentence is considered independently, without putting it into the context of the story, I want to ask the following:

1. Does the tense imply that Trout did not go upstairs? (Explanation: The author writes "would have gone", does this imply that he didn't go after all?)
2. What does Billy want? What does (doesn't) he ask of Trout?
3. Does (doesn't) Trout respect his wishes? Does or doesn't Trout go upstairs?

While I am sure that double negatives must have been discussed several times on Stack Exchange, I hope that my example being different will prevent this question from being a duplicate.

Comment: Trout did not go upstairs because Billy asked him not to:  Trout:  Hey, look stairs- I'm gonna go up.  Billy:  No, please don't go up there.  Trout:  Ok, I won't, but only because you asked me not to.

Comment: There's no double negative.  The first negative applies to the verb "ask".  The second "not" applies to the implied verbal phrase "to go upstairs".

Comment: Trout would have gone upstairs **even** if Billy hadn't asked him not to. The fact that Billy **did** ask him not to only made him more determined to do that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach While I'm not familiar with this passage from Vonnegut's book, the main verb "would have gone" strongly implies that Trout **did not** go upstair.

Comment: No, it doesn't. "Terry went upstairs. He would have gone upstairs if Brian had asked him to; he would have gone upstairs if Brian had asked him not to. *He* decided what to do, not Brian."

Comment: @AndrewLeach So are you quoting from the actual text?  Is the OP's quote from the actual text?

Comment: It seems from the actual text of the novel (pg 176), that Kilgore Trout does not accompany Billy upstairs.  I see nothing in the passage, either preceding it or following it, which indicate that Trout went upstairs despite what Billy asked him.  I'm not sure who Terry or Brian are in this context.

Comment: No, that's why I changed the names. I assert that "would have gone" does not imply that he did not go. If Vonnegut intended that meaning, then this **is** a double negative, and not standard English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach In that case, I must politely disagree with you.  Namely, I'm asserting that this is very standard English, there is no double negative, and the use of "would have gone" implies that Trout did not in fact go upstair.

Comment: @AndrewLeach WIthout extra context, _would have_ normally implies that something didn't happen. You're right that there are some contexts where it can be used otherwise, but in isolation this would be the expectation. As mentioned in other comments, we usually add _even if_ in those cases.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Your interpretation is completely at odds with the way the sentence reads.  (Ie, you're wrong.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Trout went upstairs. Billy hadn't asked him not to. *But* if he had asked Trout not to go upstairs, it would have made no difference, Trout would have gone upstairs in any case. (Is that what you meant?)

Comment: @HotLicks    If you were to isolate the sentence without knowing whether Trout did or didn't go upstairs it could be interpreted the following ways. 1) Trout really wanted to go upstairs, no one stopped him, so he did. (Billy hadn't said anything) = Trout would have gone upstairs if Billy hadn't told him not to.  It didn't matter to Trout if Billy asked him not to. 2) Trout wanted to go upstairs but Billy told him not to = Trout would have gone upstairs, if he hadn't listened and obeyed Billy's request.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I choose to interpret it the way a normal native English speaker would.

Comment: @HotLicks but is it *possible* to interpret that sentence differently? My first reaction was yours, but then I looked at it differently, read AL's comments and I saw from which angle he was coming from.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Reading (and properly understanding) English requires interpreting a lot of "implications" that a mechanical analysis of the text will not reveal.  The implication of "would have gone upstairs if", absent an *immediate* contradiction, is that he did not go upstairs.  Yes, you can interpret it differently, but such different interpretations are wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks OK, you're saying there's only one correct interpretation. It's seems a little dogmatic, but I respect your viewpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Usually when people talk about a "double negative" they mean a construction like

> I didn't see no-one.

where a negative-polarity item like *no*, *none*, *nothing* is in the scope of an explicitly negative verb. They are of note because standard varieties of English don't allow them (and people try to rationalise the objection by the claim that the above "means" *I saw someone*).

That's not the case here, as both negatives are *not* (*hadn't* = *had not*), and they're in different clauses: *if Billy hadn't* and *not to*.

So though you could call this a double negative, it is actually a straightforward application of the two negative senses.

For the other question, as others have said *would have* does imply that he didn't.

Answer (score 2):

> [does] "would have gone"... imply that he didn't go after all?

Basically, yes.

It's a double negative, but here the doubled negative does not cancel out, but rather strengthens, It intensifies the negation, meaning it's a [negative concord](http://www.cambridgescholars.com/download/sample/60949) (NC) which was common in Middle English; some scholars say it's gone from the language; others say it's still around but less commonly that in other (eg Romance) languages.

> It is largely assumed that the loss of NC was the outcome of  prescriptive views on language use...

I've read three scholarly parers and am none the wiser (it's practically a foreign language to me) as to why. But it makes sense to me, and does not seem to me to be nonstandard usage. It reads clearly, and without ambiguity.

> Particularly striking is the asymmetry between variation in the first and the second negative elements. Only five negators act as the first element in a clause containing a negative concord structure. Of these, *n’t/not* is used in…88% or almost nine out of ten of all cases.

For example, in response to "How can you admire a man like that?" one can answer:

> I can’t *not* admire him.

The way this is phrased, it intensifies the admiration.

The context is

> Kilgore Trout was shadowing him, keen to know what Billy had suspected or seen...
>
> Billy fled upstairs in his nice white home.
>
> **Trout would have come upstairs if Billy hadn’t told him not to.** Then Billy went into the bathroom, which was dark. He closed and locked the door. He left it dark, and gradually became aware that he was not alone. His son was there.

(Billy is being thrown around backwards and forwards through time. Trout is a guy who wants to prove time warps exist, and he suspects Billy is experiencing them. So, Trout was following Billy around hoping to learn something.

Billy wanted to be alone. He knew that *if he did not ask Trout* **not** *to come upstairs*, Trout would have followed him up, because Trout was shadowing Billy for evidence is the existence of time warps. So Billy asks Trout not to come up. As a result, Trout did not follow him.)

It's a double negative, but here the doubled negative intensifies the negation, meaning it's a negative concord.

I've read three scholarly parers and am none the wiser (it's practically a foreign language to me) as to why. But it makes sense to me, and does not seem to be nonstandard usage.

If the following makes any sense to you, maybe you can explain it.

[image]

<sub>from [*Negative Concord in Standard English and the syntax-morphology interface*](http://filcat.uab.cat/clt/ConsoleXVIII/tubau.pdf) by Susagna Tubau</sub>
<sub>*Aspects of English Negation*, Yoko Iyeiri</sub>

Comment: Yes, but the OP is asking about the sentence in its isolated sense. In context of the story, it is clearly what you have described but Andrew Leach's comments (which btw no one agrees with) describes a  different scenario. And I think I can see where he's coming from.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - the context doesn't really matter. It was because of Andrew's interpretation that I answered this at all. To me, this is not non-standard English, and it was clear that Trout didn't go up. I just added the context to prove it to the OP.